# How to fix this error about installing netsimulyzer into ns3.33?

Tags: ns-3

I have installed both the actual 3D visualization tool and the ns-3 companion module according to two websites list below:
https://www.projectguideline.com/installing-netsimulyzer-3d-visualization-tool-under-debian-ubuntu/
https://www.projectguideline.com/installing-netsimulyzer-3d-visualization-support-module-in-ns-3-under-debian-ubuntu/

When I reconfigured ns3 , it appears such erro 'Could not find a task generator for the name 'ns3-NetSimulyzer' '

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAdUn.png)

My ns3 is 3.33 and the environment is WSL2+Ubuntu20.04.

I have searched some pages, someone say  changing the folder name , I could't fully understand it and the suggestion didn't work.

If someone can help me fix this error, thank you in advance.